# Ubuntu bash terminal under wsl unexpectedly switches to "jump over the words" input mode

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, console

Below I assume that there are two input modes for terminal (console):

1. in "normal mode" when you press <kbd>←</kbd> your cursor moves to the left **by 1 symbol**, when you press <kbd>→</kbd> your cursor moves to the right **by 1 symbol** (or doesn't moves at all, if already in the begin/end of input)
2. in "jump over the words" mode when you press <kbd>←</kbd> your cursor moves to the left **by 1 word** to the previous space symbol, when you press <kbd>→</kbd> your cursor moves to the right **by 1 word** to the next space symbol (or doesn't moves at all, if already in the begin/end of input)

By default there is "normal mode". To use "jump over the words" mode just once (this is useful e.g. when editing commands from history), you should press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> instead of <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd>.

The problem is sometimes (I don't know what causes it) my terminal unexpectedly switches to "jump over the words" input mode permanently, and so I get my cursor jumping over the words on <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd> pressing.

What is the reason on this behavior? How to return default input mode back, when it switched, without exiting terminal?

I face this problem only on current setup, so it might be related to my certain environment. I use `bash` in Ubuntu 22.04 running under `wsl2`, accessed via Windows Terminal <del>1.18.2822.0</del> 1.18.3181.0 ("New Windows Terminal", not old `cmd.exe` nor newer `PowerShell.exe`).

Codes of <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd> when on normal mode: `^[[D^[[C`, when on sudden words-jumping mode: `^[OD^[OC`

Codes of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> when pressed obviously: `^[[1;5D^[[1;5C`

```
cat ~/.inputrc

"\e[2~": overwrite-mode
"\e[5~": beginning-of-history
"\e[6~": end-of-history
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\eOC": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
"\eOD": backward-word
"\C-h": backward-kill-word
```

Comment: Just in case, I replaced the hardware keyboard with a new one. Problem still exists. This was not caused by a keyboard malfunction (stuck keys, etc.)

Comment: I found this [PowerShell bug-report](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/issues/658) for Linux, which might be pertinent. It says that whenever the event processing of the entered characters takes too long, the tty decides to print the output because it wasn't consumed. After that, pressing any key will result in a `^[O` character on the console. Do you have anything which could slow-down the processing of the entered characters so that `^[[D^` gets a `^[O`  inserted in the middle of the sequence?

Comment: I have no idea of what could slow down input processing on my local machine. But my internet connection is kinda unstable DSL and when working on remote shell via ssh sometimes I see freezes (pressed key does not appear in the terminal as a symbol immediately, but after 1-2-3 seconds). I will try to track if my input-problem starts after such a remote-shell-input-freeze.

Comment: If this is happening on ssh, this could be a good explanation, if a glitch caused the later part of the key-characters to be lost.

Answer (score 2):

One of your programs outputs a terminal control code to enable the **"Application Keys" mode**, which switches many special keys to alternate sequences. For example, it makes the [number-pad keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_key_(DEC)) output their own special sequences instead of plain symbols (allowing e.g. <kbd>Num 2</kbd> to be distinguished from regular <kbd>2</kbd> – used to be important for ancient DEC text editors such as [EDT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EDT_(Digital))).

Then the program forgets to disable that mode again. (For example, you might have been using a full-screen text editor over SSH, then the SSH connection was closed without giving the editor a chance to clean up. I've also had similar issues with Wine on Linux, even when it was running locally.)

One *symptom* of this mode is that cursor keys begin using the `ESC O` prefix instead of the regular CSI. And while that's not *meant* to be "backward one word" in this mode, it just happens to collide with another dialect of the key sequences where it *does* mean that – I suspect Rxvt, which doesn't report modifiers the same way Xterm-style terminals do, but instead uses e.g. `ESC O d` for Ctrl-left. (Though Rxvt uses lowercase `abcd` while the keys send uppercase, so I'm really not 100% sure if this is a conflict with Rxvt specifically; it could be something else along those lines.)

The other problem is that Bash's key mappings apparently are static; instead of looking at $TERM and loading the keys from the terminfo database it has a static "best effort" mix of mappings for multiple terminals. And because Bash does not *expect* to be running in the 'Application Keys' mode, its mappings assume "`ESC O D` is *Ctrl*-Left in Normal mode" so it moves backwards one word.

Search for DECCKM in [Xterm control Sequences](https://www.xfree86.org/current/ctlseqs.html) for more details; the document has both the relevant control sequences and even a table of which keys are remapped to what input sequences.

Terminfo knows how to control this mode, so you can exit it using **`tput rmkx`** which is the inverse of `tput smkx`.<sup>1</sup> However, usually that's not the only mode that stays unexpectedly enabled, so instead of the above 'tput' or 'printf' I would recommend running **`reset`** to hopefully clear out all unwanted terminal state.

(For example, if the problem is indeed caused by a full-screen text editor, then you'll also be in the "Alternate Screen" mode which disables scrollback – `tput rmcup` to get out, `tput smcup` to enter it again – and you'll probably have mouse reporting enabled, etc.)

<sup>1</sup> (Use `infocmp` to see the sequences being used. If you prefer doing it manually without terminfo, the mode is controlled through the DECSET sequence `CSI ? Pm h` / `CSI ? Pm l` with Pm=1 for DECCKM, so you can use `printf '\e[?1l'` to disable the mode or `\e[?1h` to enable.)

> accessed via Windows Terminal 1.18.2822.0 1.18.3181.0 ("New Windows Terminal", not old cmd.exe nor newer PowerShell.exe).

cmd.exe is not a terminal, it's a pure shell much like Bash. The "old style" console window is a system component called Conhost (and is the same between cmd.exe and PowerShell).

It's probably relevant here that cmd.exe doesn't *use* Conhost like a terminal – in fact, Conhost dnd't have any 'terminal'-like capabilities at all until Windows 8.1 – instead it uses the older "Windows Console" model which uses out-of-band control APIs instead of ESC sequences, so there is no opportunity for stray ESC sequences to do much. (In addition to that, line-editing within cmd.exe is also handled *entirely* by Conhost, not by Cmd; although in PowerShell it shifts towards a more Unix-like architecture.)

Comment: `reset` is much slower than `tput reset`, could `tput reset` be used to solve the problem?